# Wordpress wrong home url - no ftp - no phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress

What can i do. I set wrong url to home url variable via wp-admin. Should be     `"http://example.com"` i set     `"http://http//example.com"`. Is there a way i can login to wp-admin. I was trying to change location in login form action parameter via dev. tools, but after that wordpress redirect me to `"http://http//example.com"`

Is there a way to get inside wp-admin without access to database/ftp/cpanel?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't change it back without FTP or database access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get access to your database. Call your host. You can use phpmyadmin to change entries in the wp_options table in the daytabase.